# Are KKT points necessarily saddle points of the Lagrangian?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider this simple toy example of an optimization problem using the method of KKT-multipliers:

minimize $3x$ s.t. $x\le3, x\ge-1$

This gives us the following Lagrangian: $L(x,u,v)=3x+u(-x-1)+v(x-3)$.

Obviously, the optimal solution $x^*=-1$, which corresponds to KKT point (-1,3,0).
This nullifies the partial of L w respect to $x$ i.e. $\nabla_xL =3-u+v = 3-3+0=0$.
It also obviously fulfills the other KKT criteria (primally and dually feasible, complementary slackness).

However, since there is no x that can both fulfill $-x-1=0$ and $x-3=0$, (the partials with respect to the KKT multipliers) the full $\nabla L$ can never be zero and there can be no stationary and thus no saddle point of the Lagrangian. Yet many sources, including wikipedia talk about KKT points in relation to saddle points. For example: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush–Kuhn–Tucker_conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) (The main theorem and the introductary sentences mentioning "saddle-point-theorem".

[https://sites.math.washington.edu/~burke/crs/516/notes/saddlepoints.pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Eburke/crs/516/notes/saddlepoints.pdf) states

> Conversely, if  ̄x is a solution
> to P at which the Slater C.Q. is satisfied, then there is a  ̄y ∈K such that ( ̄x,  ̄y) is a saddle
> point for L

Slater's conditions is obviously fulfilled for this problem, since every involved function is affine and there exists a strictly feasible x.

Where am I going wrong?

Am I confused about KKT multipliers or is saddle point simply meant to mean "stationary w.r.t x" in this context?

Comment: @Oliver Diaz Thanks for trying to improve the question, I'm pretty new on Math@SE. However, why remove the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker tag?

Comment: Because it is not an area of mathematics, but a particular subject within optimization. Those familiar with economics and optimization will know what KKT means from looking at your problem.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Just for future questions, does that mean tags like that one should generally not be used?

Comment: The pdf I linked seems to include another definition of saddle point (with what I assume is a typo; I think the $y$ should be $\bar{y}$ in the right-hand side of the equation) , under which this KKT point is indeed a saddle point. Can it generally be assumed that all discussion of this method operates under this definition of saddle point?

Comment: All that fits within the real of convex-optimization. People who may have something to say (in the way of an answer) will likely have experience if that subject. Tags that are too (for example "card-theorem", "Ito-integral", "martingale-convergence") may be a little redundant. But hey!, that is just my opinion.

Comment: @OliverDiaz The [tag:Karush-Kuhn-Tucker] tag seems to fit this question well. I might agree if the asker invented the tag, but since it already exists, I think it fits here just fine.

Comment: @JMC: you are right, there is a typo in the definition. The notion of saddle points there is standard in (convex) optimizaion imho.

Comment: @daw Do you know how this definition relates to the usual definition of "zero gradient but not local extremum"? When the point considered is not at the "border" of its domain, a saddle point in this convex-opt sense should also be one according to the "usual" definition, I think, but what about the other direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of the saddle point that is confusing you is:
$$
L(x^*,u^*,v^*) \ge L(x^*,u,v)
$$
for all $u\ge0$, $v\ge0$. These inequality constraints on the multipliers to inequality constraints need to be taken into account.

This saddle point property is true for your case:
$$
L(x^*,u,v) = 3x^*+u(−x^*−1)+v(x^*−3) = -3 -4v.
$$
(for $x^*=-1$). This is maximal over non-negative $u,v$ if $v=0$.

Comment: That makes sense. My problem was that I was thinking about saddle points naively as in "gradient = 0, but not an extremum" and not in terms of the definition common in convex optimization.

Comment: I'm gonna accept this because of your comment on the OP about the definition of saddle point in this context. As for the title question: afaict, in general a KKT point is only a saddle point in this sense if another qualification of the involved functions such as convexity is fulfilled.

Comment: @JMC yes, you are right. Convexity is essential for this implication. As you posted the question under convex analysis/optimization, I assume convexity was a given.

Answer (score 2):

The KKT point is only a saddle point of the *unconstrained* Lagrangian when there are no inequality constraints.

When there are inequality constraints, the KKT is a saddle point of the Lagrangian *subject to* the dual feasibility constraints (in your case, $u\geq 0$ and $v\geq 0$).

In your case, the point $(x,u,v) = (-1,3,0)$ is a saddle point in this sense (the gradient, projected onto the feasible set, is zero; and the Lagrangian increases in the $(-1,1,0)$ direction and decreases in the $(1,1,0)$ direction.)

Comment: What does "the gradient, projected onto the feasible set" mean precisely? The gradient of the Lagrangian when ignoring the variables that are =0 (in this case v?)

Comment: $\nabla L(-1,3,0)=(0,0,-4)$. Does projecting the gradient mean we map it, (possibly onto the nearest point) of the domain, i.e. lift the $-4$ to $0$ in a sense?